# Gentoo portage continue after shutdown

Tags: compiling, gentoo, shutdown

Can I rerun my command to install KDE full

after a shutdown and will it continue? I'm installing KDE and it takes a while now. I'm on my laptop and it's pretty late here. There are many packages to come.

PS the command:

```
# emerge --ask kde-base/kde-meta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cancel portage and later rerun the same command the specified package will compile again. So if you e.g. start to run `emerge www-client/firefox`, cancel it and rerun the command again, merging `www-client/firefox` will start from scratch. Note that the dependency list is generated when starting `emerge`, so when you missed some dependency in the first run which have already been merged, those are not reinstalled.

`kde-base/kde-meta` is no monolithic ebuild for kde, but a meta package, that contains only dependencies to other ebuilds. So the only progress lost when rerunning portage after a reboot is that in the ebuild that was compiling when you canceled portage / shut down.

Most packages used for kde are quite small, so chances are that you are not losing much. Some packages (e.g. `kde-base/kdelibs`) take a long time though.

One side note: If you want a usable system fast I recommend not to start with installing `kde-base/kde-meta`, but with `kde-base/kde-base-meta`. Once this is installed you can already use KDE and install the rest later. You do no lose anything when merging`kde-base/kde-meta` after this.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/rc.d/rc.local

Take a look at the rc.local file on your system, whatever you put in there will be run whenever your system boots. You could also set a cron job, based on knowing in advance when the system will reboot, which could remove your command from rc.local once the machine is done booting.

You can also put whatever you want in an init script in /etc/init.d or relevant /etc/rc.d directory.

Comment: I meant will my package install continue when I give the command to install.

Comment: Sorry it is not clear, you want to install a package which will reboot your system before the install is complete, and then resume the install after the reboot? I have not seen a *nix package install that worked like that so far.

Comment: No look, it's late here, so I should shutdown my laptop before the package install is done. So will it resume with the first package it hasn't finished?

Comment: The short answer is no. I can't say what you want is impossible, but I don't know of anything that would make your system resume the install. As far as I know, your system will just do the normal boot process. Unless the interrupted install has some mechanism to recover when it is interrupted, I think you are out of luck. If you are installing something that is affecting your boot process, you have the chance to break your system if you shut down the machine while the install is still running.

Comment: I mean portage is installing KDE in chroot, it works using drivedroid on my phone, KDE is pretty big, so when I shutdown, I'll also remove my phone, tomorrow I'm going to chroot again but will it install the rest of the packages needed for KDE?